# Remainder of division of $r(x)h(x)$ by $g(x)h(x)$ (that is known to have degree less than degree of $g(x)$) is equal to that of $r(x)$ by $g(x)$

Tags: polynomials

Is the conclusion below correct?

> Remainder of division of $r(x)h(x)$ by $g(x)h(x)$ (that is known to have degree less than degree of $g(x)$) is equal to remainder of division of $r(x)$ by $g(x)$ ?

Comment: Only if the remainder is $0$.

Comment: @egreg or if $h(x)=1$

Comment: @Tim.Ratigan I was disregarding the obvious case. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

No.  Division of a polynomial $P(x)$ by $D(x)$ takes the form $P(x)=Q(x)D(x)+R(x)$, where $R$ is the remainder and satisfies $\deg R<\deg Q$.  Let $r(x)=g(x)Q(x)+R(x)$, where $\deg R<\deg g$.  Then $r(x)h(x)=g(x)h(x)Q(x)+R(x)h(x)$, where the remainder satisfies $$\deg (R\cdot h)=\deg R+\deg h<\deg g+\deg h=\deg(g\cdot h)$$  In conclusion, the remainder is multiplied by $h(x)$, but is not the same.

Comment: that just means that you've found a remainder.

Comment: Presuming that $R$ is the remainder of $r(x)/h(x)$, as I did above, we obtain that the remainder when $r(x)h(x)$ is divided by $g(x)h(x)$ is $R(x)h(x)$, which I also said above.

Comment: I've edited the question. Would you mind talking a look at it again? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct, any more than the remainder in the division of $50$ by $20$ is the same as the remainder in the division of $5$ by $2$.

What’s true is that the remainder in the division of $rh$ by $gh$ is $h$ times the remainder in the division of $r$ by $g$.

Answer (score -1):

While to show that something is true it is necessary a full demonstration, to verify that it is wrong one example is enough, so let's get $$r=3, h=5, g=2$$. $$r\%g=3\%2=1$$ $$(rh)\%(gh)=15\%10=5$$. This shows that the assumption is **false**, infact 1 is different from 5!

Int the previous

This is the good and the bad about math... a lot of work to demonstrate something and a simple example to destroy the theory ;)

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I stated that we know that rh%gh is less than g !

Comment: ops sorry... :), I may still misunderstand your question, I am showing that r%g is different from rh%gh . @MahdiKhosravi